# Can the conversion of a malicious PDF to image be exploitable?

Tags: malware, pdf

Let's say I want to allow to the customer's of my website to upload PDF documents. What would be more safe to do:

- Convert the PDF to image using a library and store it in my file server as an image? Can the process of converting a potentially malicious PDF file be exploitable?
- Or convert the PDF to PDF/A format and store it in PDF/A format? Does this will remove all the active and harmful actions from the document?
- Is the presence of a network anti-malware product going to help?

Also, please note that after the upload, these files will not be available for my customers to view.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, it depends. Potentially every piece of code operating on user-controlled data is exploitable if it contains bugs in implementation (it does). However common pdf attacks are targeted at popular viewer applications, not automated converters, so your potential adversary is a targeted and capable hacker. They are less common, much more dangerous and are attracted to financial organizations ;)

> Can the process of converting a potentially malicious PDF file be exploitable?

Yes. Here your security depends on the security of your chosen library. For example, image processing library Imagemagic and video processing library ffmpeg have [535](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-1749/Imagemagick.html) and [314](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-3611/product_id-6315/Ffmpeg-Ffmpeg.html) CVEs respectively. Some of those allow the attacker to execute arbitrary code on your machine.

The most popular (AFAIK) pdf processing library (Apache PDFBox) is written in Java, so it's relatively hard to perform memory corruption attacks, however, it's not immune from all attacks and has [4](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-33936/Apache-Pdfbox.html) CVEs to show that. It's unfair to compare the numbers here since PDFBox is much less popular than the other two libraries.

The fact that PDF is one of the craziest formats ever invented (here, play some [breakout.pdf](https://rawgit.com/osnr/horrifying-pdf-experiments/master/breakout.pdf)) doesn't help with security.

The main takeaway is that just like a malicious image can exploit imagemagic and malicious video can exploit ffmpeg, malicious pdf can exploit your chosen library.

> Or convert the PDF to PDF/A

I would imagine that converting to PDF/A allows you to save more useful information for later processing than converting to plain image, so that's a plus. As for security, this reduces the attack surface for the readers that would subsequently open the converted PDF/A and changes codepath inside pdf converter, but it's impossible to say whether this codepath is safer or not.

Either way, you need to care about the security of your converter. The principle of least privilege is very useful here. Extract your pdf converter into a separate process/container and allow it to take pdfs from one dir, convert them, and store them in another dir. No process spawning, no network access, execution timeouts, etc.

> Is the presence of a network anti-malware product going to help?

I'm skeptical. Despite how much AV vendors push "behavioral analysis" technologies, the bulk of AV job is just comparing files with signatures of common viruses. Attack on specific pdf parser will probably be quite uncommon, perhaps even 0-day, so you shouldn't rely on AV catching it.

Some kind of network activity analysis could make the attack harder to pull off unnoticed or even prevent it, but nothing can guarantee security here.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response! What would you do in my position?

Comment: @elenaa I would probably convert to pdf/a using some memory-safe language (definitely not C or C++). I have some experience with PDFBox, so I'd use that. I'd run the converter on linux with SELinux installed and limit the converter process as much as possible. I'd also test the conversion speed and decide whether I must write a multi-threaded conversion deamon or just launch the tool every time the conversion is performed (this is easier and less error prone, but slower). The tool would take pdfs form one folder, convert them and put results in another folder, that's basically it.